# Java compare linked list with another file and remove duplicate entries

Tags: java

So I have an assignment and a little stumped on the last part (very new so bear with me).

I have two files "birds.txt" and "birds2.txt". essentially I have the first part done where it will read "birds.txt" and sort them in a list by frequency of how many times a specific bird is seen which works fine (how many times the name of any given bird appears in the "birds"txt").

The part I can't seem to wrap my head around is how I would take my existing list and compare it to my second file "birds2.txt" and then have it remove any duplicate entries. So the first and second file will have some of the same birds and if when reading the second file it finds a bird already in the list it removes it then prints this "new" list again.

I apologize if I'm not clear enough or missing any info...below is my code up to where I'm at.

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class LinkedList {

    
    class Node{    
        Bird bird;    
        Node next;    
            
        public Node(Bird bird) {    
            this.bird = bird;    
            this.next = null;    
        }    
    }    
     
    //Head and tail of the singly linked list   
    public Node head = null;    
    public Node tail = null;    
        
    //Add a new node to the list    
    public void addNewNode(Bird bird) {    
        //Create a new node    
        Node newNode = new Node(bird);    
            
        //Checks if the list is empty    
        if(head == null) {    
            //If list is empty head and tail points to the newNode    
            head = newNode;    
            tail = newNode;    
        }    
        else {    
            //Only tail points to the newNode
            tail.next = newNode;     
            tail = newNode;    
        }    
    }    
        
    
    public int getCount() {  // to get a count of nodes in the list
        if (head != null) {
            Node current = head;
            int count = 0;
            while (current != null)
            {
                count++;
                current = current.next;
            }
            return count;
        }else
        return 0;
    }

     
    public void printList() {    
        Node current = head;    
            
        if(head == null) {    
            System.out.println("List is empty");    
            return;    
        }    
        System.out.println("Nodes: ");    
        while(current != null) {    
            //Prints each node   
            System.out.print("["+current.bird + "] ");    
            current = current.next;    
        }    
        System.out.println();    
    }    
        
    public Bird GetNth(int index)  // to get a bird object from a node
    {
        Node current = head;
        int count = 0; /* index of Node we are
                          currently looking at */
        while (current != null)
        {
            if (count == index)
                return current.bird;
            count++;
            current = current.next;
        }
        return null;
    }
        
    public void sortListByFrequency() { 
          
        Node current = head;
        Node nextNode = null;  
        Bird temp;  
          
        if(head == null) {  
            return;  
        }  
        else {  
            while(current != null) {  
                nextNode = current.next;  
                  
                while(nextNode != null) {  
                    
                     //Swap nodes content if next node's bird count is lower
                    if(current.bird.getBirdCount() < nextNode.bird.getBirdCount()) {  
                        temp = current.bird;  
                        current.bird = nextNode.bird;  
                        nextNode.bird = temp;  
                    }  
                    nextNode = nextNode.next;  
                }  
                current = current.next;  
            }      
        }  
    }  


    public static void main(String[] args) {    
            
      readFile();
    }    

    static void readFile() {
        // 
             try {
                 LinkedList list = new LinkedList(); // create the Singly Linked List           
                    FileReader fr = new FileReader("resource/birds.txt"); //access birds.txt
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

                    String currentLine = br.readLine();
                    
                    while(currentLine != null) {
                        
                        
                        String s = currentLine; // obtain the string 


                        if (list.head==null) {  // if the list is empty, add a new node and make it a head
                            Bird a = new Bird(s);
                            list.addNewNode(a);
                        }
                
                        for (int i = 0; i < list.getCount(); i++) { // if the SSL is not empty, go thru the nodes and find a matching bird name
                            String currentBird = list.GetNth(i).getBirdName();
                            if (s.equals(currentBird)) {
                                list.GetNth(i).addBirdCount();  // if bird was found, add an increment
                                break;
                            }
                            if (i == list.getCount()-1 && !s.equals(currentBird)) { // if bird is not found, add a new node
                                Bird a = new Bird(s);
                                list.addNewNode(a);
                            }
                        }
                            currentLine = br.readLine();
                                
                        }
                       br.close();
                       fr.close();
                       System.out.println("List not sorted: "+"\n");
                       list.printList(); // print all nodes as part of SLL
                       System.out.println("");
                       System.out.println("List sorted by frequency: "+"\n");
                       list.sortListByFrequency();
                       list.printList();
                    
             } 
             
                    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        System.out.println("File not found");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    catch (IOException e) {
                        System.out.println("File not found");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                     
         
}
}


Bird Class


public class Bird {
    private String birdName = "";
    private int birdCount = 0;
    
    
    public Bird(String s) {
        this.birdName = s;
        this.birdCount = 0;
    }
    
    public String getBirdName() {
        String s = birdName;
        return s;
    }
    
    public int getBirdCount() {
        int n = birdCount;
        return n;
    }
    
    public void addBirdCount() {
        int n = getBirdCount();
        n++;
        this.birdCount = n;
    }
    
       @Override
       public String toString() {
            return (""+this.getBirdName()+
                        " : "+ this.getBirdCount());
       }
}
```

Comment: Could you please share content of Bird class?

Comment: Why the hyperlink tag?

Comment: You may need to be more specific about which part you’re struggling with. Removing from a linked list, testing if two Birds are equal, finding duplicate entries between two collections (iteration, as a potential means), or reading in a second file. Although breaking it down into those points may also help find your own solution to this.

Comment: If this is a schoolwork assignment, and you must do it the hard way (without using utility classes), say so. Or is this real work? That affects the kind of Answers to be provided.

Comment: @RohanKumar I edited the original post to add Bird class

And this is school work not real work.

Comment: could you please share `birds.txt` content too?

Comment: @RohanKumar

bird.txt ````Robin Starling House Sparrow Robin Chickadee Grackle House Sparrow Cardinal Indigo Bunting Robin Starling House Sparrow Robin Chickadee Grackle Chickadee Grackle House Sparrow Cardinal Purple Martin Chickadee Grackle House Sparrow Cardinal Starling Robin Robin Ruby Throated Humming Bird Blue Jay Purple Martin Chickadee Grackle House Sparrow Cardinal Starling Robin```` bird.2txt ````Robin Grackle Starling Chickadee```` bird.txt is longer then what I posted but just put a bit to give you an idea

Comment: Sorry for another question, while comparing second file, do we need to take frequency into account too? When you say remove do you mean remove node entirely or just decrease it's frequency? What should be expected output of the input you shared above?

Comment: @RohanKumar The frequency needs to be left alone. So basically for example in both birds.txt and birds2.txt they both have ````Robin```` in it so Robin needs to be removed completely from the list 

Hope that makes sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think deletion while comparing with strings loaded from file is somewhat similar to first part of your problem where you were adding items to the list. You can create a method in your class which will scan the file line by line, search for a match for that line in linked list and remove if it's a match.

I was able to do that with three helper methods:

```java
/*
 * Scan provided file line by line and delete list nodes
 * whose bird name is equal to any bird name found in input
 * file.
 */
public void scanAndCompareFileEntriesAndRemoveNode(File file) throws IOException {
    if (!file.exists()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not able to find file for comparison");
    }

    try (FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr)) {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            boolean deletionStatus = removeBirdWithName(line);
            if (deletionStatus) {
                System.out.printf("Successfully deleted %s from list", line);
            }
        }
    }
}

/*
 * Remove Node with bird name equal to specified bird name.
 */
private boolean removeBirdWithName(String name) {
    Node currentNode = head;
    Node prevNode = null;
    boolean birdFoundAndDeleted = false;

    while (currentNode != null) {
        if (currentNode.bird.getBirdName().equals(name)) {
            removeNodeFromLinkedList(prevNode, currentNode);
            birdFoundAndDeleted = true;
        }

        prevNode = currentNode;
        currentNode = currentNode.next;
    }
    return birdFoundAndDeleted;
}

/*
 * Remove Single Node from Linked List.
 */
private void removeNodeFromLinkedList(Node prevNode, Node currentNode) {
    if (prevNode == null) {
        head = currentNode.next;
    } else {
        prevNode.next = currentNode.next;
    }
}
```

I tested this code by adding these additional code to your `main()` method:

```java
File secondFile = new File(LinkedList.class.getResource("/bird2.txt").getFile());
list.scanAndCompareFileEntriesAndRemoveNode(secondFile);
list.printList();
```

This gives the following output:

```
List not sorted: 

Nodes: 
[Robin : 7] [Starling : 4] [House : 4] [Sparrow : 4] [Chickadee : 5] [Grackle : 5] [Cardinal : 4] [Indigo : 1] [Bunting : 1] [Purple : 1] [Martin : 2] [House Sparrow : 2] [Ruby : 1] [Throated Humming Bird : 1] [Blue Jay Purple : 1] 

List sorted by frequency: 

Nodes: 
[Robin : 7] [Chickadee : 5] [Grackle : 5] [Sparrow : 4] [Starling : 4] [House : 4] [Cardinal : 4] [Martin : 2] [House Sparrow : 2] [Purple : 1] [Indigo : 1] [Bunting : 1] [Ruby : 1] [Throated Humming Bird : 1] [Blue Jay Purple : 1] 

Comparing and Removing List nodes from /home/rohaan/Documents/stackoverflow-code/java-posts/target/classes/bird2.txt
Successfully deleted Robin from list
Successfully deleted Grackle from list
Successfully deleted Starling from list
Successfully deleted Chickadee from list
Nodes: 
[Sparrow : 4] [House : 4] [Cardinal : 4] [Martin : 2] [House Sparrow : 2] [Purple : 1] [Indigo : 1] [Bunting : 1] [Ruby : 1] [Throated Humming Bird : 1] [Blue Jay Purple : 1]
```

Comment: If I could just ask one more question where in the main() did you add the below exactly?

````File secondFile = new File(LinkedList.class.getResource("/bird2.txt").getFile());
list.scanAndCompareFileEntriesAndRemoveNode(secondFile);
list.printList();```` @rohankumar

Comment: ah, sorry It's not in main() but in readfile() method. You can see modified version of your class here: https://github.com/rohanKanojia/stackoverflow-code/blob/master/java-posts/src/main/java/in/rohaan/LinkedList.java#L222

Comment: Thanks Rohan, I was able to figure it out shortly after but very much appreciate your help!